# Mostrar ordenadas las entradas de un registro en c++

Tags: c++, ordenamiento, registro, ordenar

Hola que tal tengo un programa de captura de datos de empleados que lleva las siguientes funciones:

1. Añadir datos de un nuevo Empleado
2. Mostrar los nombres de todos los Empleados
3. Mostrar Empleados que sean de mas de un cierta Edad
4. Ver datos de un Empleados
5. Mostar Empleados Ordenados Por No. de Empleado
6. Mostar Empleados por No. de Empleado
7. Mostar Empleados Ordenados Por No. de Departamento
8. Mostar Empleados por No. de Departamento

**Tengo casi todas las funciones pero en la 5 y 7  trate de ordenarlos y  lo hace pero modifica los valores originales del registro**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
struct tipoDatos
{
    string NombreEmp;
    int  edad,noE,noD;   
    char cel[10];
     string rfc;
    
};
 
int numeroFichas=0;  // Número de fichas que ya tenemos
int i;               // Para bucles
int opcion;          // La opcion del menu que elija el usuario
 
string textoTemporal; // Para pedir datos al usuario
int numeroTemporal;
 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    tipoDatos *fichas = new tipoDatos[1000];
 
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        system("color 80");
        cout << "Escoja una opción:" << endl;
        cout << "1.- Añadir datos de un nuevo Empleado" << endl;
        cout << "2.- Mostrar los nombres de todos los Empleados" << endl;
        cout << "3.- Mostrar Empleados que sean de mas de un cierta Edad" << endl;
        cout << "4.- Ver datos de un Empleados" << endl;
        cout << "5.- Mostar Empleados Ordenados Por No. de Empleado" << endl;
        cout <<"6.- Mostar Empleados por No. de Empleado"<<endl;
        cout <<"7.- Mostar Empleados Ordenados Por No. de Departamento" << endl;
        cout <<"8.- Mostar Empleados por No. de Departamento"<<endl;
        cin >> opcion;
        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1: 
                if (numeroFichas < 1000)  
                {
                    cout<<"======Introducir Empleados======"<<endl;
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Introduce el nombre del Empleado: ";
                    cin >> fichas[numeroFichas].NombreEmp;
                    cout << "Introduce la edad del Empleado: ";
                    cin >> fichas[numeroFichas].edad;
                    cout << "Introduce el RFC del Empleado: ";
                    cin >> fichas[numeroFichas].rfc;
                    cout << "Introduce el Numero de Celular del Empleado: ";
                    cin >> fichas[numeroFichas].cel;
                    cout << "Introduce el Numero de Empleado: ";
                    cin >> fichas[numeroFichas].noE;
                    cout << "Introduce el Numero de Departamento del Empleado: ";
                    cin >> fichas[numeroFichas].noD;
                    numeroFichas++;  
                }
                else  
                cout << "Máximo de Empleados alcanzado (1000)!" << endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
 
            case 2: // Mostrar todos
                system("cls");
                cout<<"======Todos los Empleados======"<<endl;
                for (i=0; i<numeroFichas; i++)
                   cout <<"\n||Empleado: " << fichas[i].NombreEmp<<endl
                   << "||Edad: " << fichas[i].edad<<endl
                   << "||RFC: " << fichas[i].rfc<<endl
                   << "||Celular: " << fichas[i].cel<<endl
                   << "||No.Empleado: " << fichas[i].noE<<endl
                   << "||N.Departamento: " << fichas[i].noD<<endl;
                  
                             
                system("pause");
                break;
 
            case 3: // Mostrar según la edad 
                system("cls");
                cout<<"======Empleados a Partir de Años======"<<endl;
                cout << "¿A partir de que Edad quieres que te muestre? ";
                cin >> numeroTemporal;
                for (i=0; i<numeroFichas; i++)
                    if (fichas[i].edad >= numeroTemporal){
                    
                   cout <<"\n||Empleado: " << fichas[i].NombreEmp<<endl
                   << "||Edad: " << fichas[i].edad<<endl
                   << "||RFC: " << fichas[i].rfc<<endl
                   << "||Celular: " << fichas[i].cel<<endl
                   << "||No.Empleado: " << fichas[i].noE<<endl
                   << "||N.Departamento: " << fichas[i].noD<<endl;
                   cout<<""<<endl;
                }
                system("pause");
                break;
 
            case 4: // Ver todos los datos por nombre
                system("cls");
                cout<<"======Empleados por Nombre======"<<endl;
                cout << "¿De qué Empleado quieres ver todos los datos?";
                cin >> textoTemporal;
                for (i=0; i<numeroFichas; i++)
                {
                    if (fichas[i].NombreEmp == textoTemporal){
                             
                       cout <<"\n||Empleado: " << fichas[i].NombreEmp<<endl
                   << "||Edad: " << fichas[i].edad<<endl
                   << "||RFC: " << fichas[i].rfc<<endl
                   << "||Celular: " << fichas[i].cel<<endl
                   << "||No.Empleado: " << fichas[i].noE<<endl
                   << "||N.Departamento: " << fichas[i].noD<<endl;
                   cout<<""<<endl;}
                   
                }
                system("pause");
                break;
 
            case 5: 

                //Aqui es donde se ordena
                system("cls");
                cout<<"======Empleados Ordenados por No.Empleado ======"<<endl;
                float temporal;
                for (int k = 0 ;k < numeroFichas; k++){
                for (int l = 0; l< numeroFichas-1; l++){
                    if (fichas[l].noE > fichas[l+1].noE){ 
                    temporal = fichas[l].noE; 
                    fichas[l].noE = fichas[l+1].noE; 
                    fichas[l+1].noE = temporal;
                }
                }
                
                }
                for (i=0; i<numeroFichas; i++){
                cout <<"\n||Empleado: " << fichas[i].NombreEmp<<endl
                   << "||Edad: " << fichas[i].edad<<endl
                   << "||RFC: " << fichas[i].rfc<<endl
                   << "||Celular: " << fichas[i].cel<<endl
                   << "||No.Empleado: " << fichas[i].noE<<endl
                   << "||N.Departamento: " << fichas[i].noD<<endl;
                }
                system("pause");
                
                break;
                
            case 6:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"======Empleados por No.Empleado ======"<<endl;
                cout << "Ingresa El Numero de Empleado";
                cin >> numeroTemporal;
                for (i=0; i<numeroFichas; i++)
                    if (fichas[i].noE == numeroTemporal){
                   cout <<"\n||Empleado: "<<fichas[i].NombreEmp<<endl
                   << "||Edad: " << fichas[i].edad<<endl
                   << "||RFC: " << fichas[i].rfc<<endl
                   << "||Celular: " << fichas[i].cel<<endl
                   << "||No.Empleado: " << fichas[i].noE<<endl
                   << "||N.Departamento: " << fichas[i].noD<<endl;
                   cout<<""<<endl;
                }
                system("pause");
                break;
                
           


                case 7:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"======Empleados Ordenados por Departamento ======"<<endl;
                float temp;
                for (int k = 0 ;k < numeroFichas; k++){
                for (int l = 0; l< numeroFichas-1; l++){
                    if (fichas[l].noD > fichas[l+1].noD){ 
                    temp = fichas[l].noD; 
                    fichas[l].noD = fichas[l+1].noD; 
                    fichas[l+1].noD = temp;
                }
                }
                
                }
                for (i=0; i<numeroFichas; i++){
                cout <<"\n||Empleado: " << fichas[i].NombreEmp<<endl
                   << "||Edad: " << fichas[i].edad<<endl
                   << "||RFC: " << fichas[i].rfc<<endl
                   << "||Celular: " << fichas[i].cel<<endl
                   << "||No.Empleado: " << fichas[i].noE<<endl
                   << "||N.Departamento: " << fichas[i].noD<<endl;
                }
                system("pause");
                
                break;
                
            case 8:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"======Empleados por Departamento ======"<<endl;
                cout << "Ingresa El Numero de Departamento";
                cin >> numeroTemporal;
                for (i=0; i<numeroFichas; i++)
                    if (fichas[i].noD == numeroTemporal){
                   cout <<"\n||Empleado: "<<fichas[i].NombreEmp<<endl
                   << "||Edad: " << fichas[i].edad<<endl
                   << "||RFC: " << fichas[i].rfc<<endl
                   << "||Celular: " << fichas[i].cel<<endl
                   << "||No.Empleado: " << fichas[i].noE<<endl
                   << "||N.Departamento: " << fichas[i].noD<<endl;
                   cout<<""<<endl;
                }
                system("pause");
            break;
            
            case 9:
                 cout << "Fin del programa" << endl;
                break;
 
            default: 
                cout << "Opción desconocida!" << endl;
                break;
        }
    } while (opcion != 9); 
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Podrías ordernar en  una copia del arreglo y  mantienes el original tal cual  o añades a la estructura  el numero de secuencia en que fueron ingresados o simplemente tienes otro arreglo solo de punteros donde se guardan las direcciones  en el orden que se requiera

Comment: Creo que te conviene aprender a utilizar funciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **trate de ordenarlos y lo hace pero modifica los valores originales del registro**

Obviamente, porque no estás cambiando la posición de los registros: estás modificando valores del registro:

```
if (fichas[l].noE > fichas[l+1].noE) {
    temporal = fichas[l].noE; 
    fichas[l].noE = fichas[l+1].noE; 
//            ^^^               ^^^ <-- Sólo cambias el valor tipoDatos::noE, no el registro
    fichas[l+1].noE = temporal;
//              ^^^ <-- Sólo cambias el valor tipoDatos::noE, no el registro
}
```

```
for (int l = 0; l< numeroFichas-1; l++) {
    if (fichas[l].noD > fichas[l+1].noD){ 
    temp = fichas[l].noD; 
    fichas[l].noD = fichas[l+1].noD; 
//            ^^^               ^^^ <-- Sólo cambias el valor tipoDatos::noD, no el registro
    fichas[l+1].noD = temp;
//              ^^^ <-- Sólo cambias el valor tipoDatos::noD, no el registro
}
```

Si quieres intercambiar los registros, hazlo con el registro entero:

```
if (fichas[l].noE > fichas[l+1].noE) {
    tipoDatos temporal = fichas[l];
    fichas[l] = fichas[l+1];
    fichas[l+1] = temporal;
}
```

```
for (int l = 0; l< numeroFichas-1; l++) {
    tipoDatos temporal = fichas[l];
    fichas[l] = fichas[l+1];
    fichas[l+1] = temporal;
}
```

O mejor aún, usa [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

```
if (fichas[l].noE > fichas[l+1].noE) {
    std::swap(fichas[l], fichas[l+1]);
}
```

```
for (int l = 0; l< numeroFichas-1; l++) {
    std::swap(fichas[l], fichas[l+1]);
}
```